# Filter records with parameters using like statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like, sql-in

I have a query to filter location by different regions based on postal code of that. To distinguish these regions, people must rely on the first 2 numbers of that and each region contains many different numbers (e.g: region A (1 to 25) and region B (26 to 30)).

So when I filter region A, the statement goes like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Address 
WHERE PostalCode LIKE '01%' 
   OR PostalCode LIKE '02%' 
   OR PostalCode LIKE '03%' 
   OR PostalCode LIKE '01%' 
   OR PostalCode LIKE '04%' 
   OR PostalCode LIKE '05%' 
   -- all the way to:
   OR PostalCode LIKE '25%'
```

That would be very long and unscientific at all. I tried to find another way like using IN statement. But it didn't work.

I need an ideal to process this issue.

Comment: `WHERE SUBSTRING(PostalCode,1,2) IN ('01','02','03','04','05','25')` should work.

Comment: select * from Address  where try_cast(int, left(postalcode, 2)) between 1 and 25

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your RDMS but you can simply get the first two chars from your postal code and perform string comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM [my_table]
WHERE LEFT(PostalCode, 2) <= '25'
```

I guess it will be better in terms of readability to cast to numeric and work with numbers.

And as alternative, in terms of performance it will be better to create a new column, populated the region code and create an index on it.

Answer (score 0):

**For Region A:**

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_
WHERE Left(RegionCode, 2) BETWEEN '01' AND '25' and Region = 'A'
```

**For Region B:**

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_
WHERE Left(RegionCode, 2) BETWEEN '26' AND '30' and Region = 'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's SQL Server, you could probably use

```
SELECT * 
FROM Address 
WHERE PostalCode LIKE N'[01-99]%'
```

This would check every postalcode that start with 01 to 99.